# User form data and database data comparing Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have following HTML form

```
 <form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="/search">
            <label for="company">Phone company</label>
            <input type="text" name="company" value="">
            <br>
            <label for="modelname">Model name</label>
            <input type="text" name="modelname" value="">
            <br>
            <label for="numbername">Model number</label>
            <input type="text" name="numbername" value="">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
```

Phone schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const phoneSchema = new Schema({
    company: String,
    modelname: String,
    numbername: String,
    picture: String,
    price: String,
});

const Phone = mongoose.model('phone', phoneSchema);

module.exports = Phone;
```

For example,I have next phone in my database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b155a66aced9b079c276ba0"),
    "company" : "Samsung",
    "modelname" : "Galaxy",
    "numbername" : "S5",
    "picture" : "https://drop.ndtv.com/TECH/product_database/images/2252014124325AM_635_samsung_galaxy_s5.jpeg",
    "price" : "12500P",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Post request handler

```
    app.post('/search', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    Phone.findOne({company: req.body.company, modelname: req.body.modelname, numbername: req.body.numbername}).then(function(){
        .......

})});
```

If company,modelname,numbername in this form are same with same database fields then I have to render page with all info from database( company + picture + price for example).How I can compare form data and database data?

Answer (score 0):

How I understand it you are trying to pass the database info back to the HTML page.  I think that this is a similar question to here: [How do I serve partially dynamic HTML pages with Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633855/how-do-i-serve-partially-dynamic-html-pages-with-express)
  If you need to filter anything you could do that with queries of which more information could be found here [How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)  If you want a kind of hacky solution you can send a xHTTP request to your server and parse the response

```
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        console.log(data)
    }
}
xhttp.open("POST", '/search', true);
xhttp.send();
</script>
```